# Only variables can be passed by reference - php

Tags: php, mysql, reference

i am trying this code, but i get this error:

```
Only variables can be passed by reference in xxx
```

script

```
class page {
  function insert($db, $of, $form, &$arr) {

      $i = 0;

      foreach(array_combine($form['value0'], $arr) as $val=>$v){

          $sql->prepare("mysqli query here");
          $sql->bind_param('ssss', $val, $of, $v[$i][0], $v[$i][1]);//error here
          $sql->execute();
          $i++;

      }
      return true;
  }
}
```

what is the reason, and how can be solved ? thanks

Comment: I don't even see where `sql` is initialized

Comment: On your error line, should $of be $oferta?

Comment: Why do you think that would fix it?

Comment: $of, but for this case, is irrelevant, the problem is about reference (&$arr).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you're using [`mysqli::bind_param`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).  All arguments except the first are passed by reference.  This means they must be variables, and not strings, array elements, etc.  I'm actually not sure *why* it needs to do this by reference, but never mind.  You can fix it pretty easily:

```
$v0 = $v[$i][0];
$v1 = $v[$i][1];
$sql->bind_param('ssss', $val, $of, $v0, $v1);
```

Comment: "Silly design decision", but it is what it is.: I suppose "so the value can be assigned to after bind but before execution?" which would allow the same `$sql` to be re-used repeatedly by only changing the value of the referenced variables... again, not how I would have designed it.