# PDO SQL single query, multiple rows and values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, json

I have this array JSON POST request to a PHP file.

```
Array
(
[user_id] => 1
[date] => 2014-12-05
[time] => 12:00
[description] => lol
[friends] => "12","9"
[PHPSESSID] => 5ae7c3e6339c528e7804020dd0f0cdbb
)
```

I try to add the values (12 | 1)  and (9 | 1) to a mysql table with a single sql query

Table:

```
u_id  |  f_id
  1   |   12
  1   |   9
```

What I have so far:

```
$friendarray = $_POST['Friends'];

foreach( $friends as $friendsarray ) {
    $values[] = "(" . $u_id . "," . $friendsarray . ")";
    }

$query = "INSERT INTO up2_friends_to_users (u_id , f_id ) VALUES ".implode(',',$values);

    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
```

As you see this is not working at all. I try to achieve something like this:

```
$query_params = array(
    ':u_id' => $_POST['user_id'],
    ':f_id' => $friendid,
```

And then would like to send it like this:

```
    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
```

Is it possible to create a single query with multiple rows like this?

**Answer thanks to RobP:**

```
        $friendsarray = explode(',',$_POST['friends']);
        $placeholders = [];

        for($i=0, $len=count($friendsarray); $i < $len; $i++) {
            $placeholders[i] .= "(:u_id".$i.", :f_id".$i.")"; // entries like "(:u_id0, :f_id0)"
        }
        $query = "INSERT INTO up2_friends_to_users (u_id , f_id ) VALUES  ".implode(",", $placeholders);
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        for($i=0, $len=count($placeholders); $i < $len; $i++) {
            $stmt->bindParam(':u_id'.$i, $_POST['user_id']);
            $nextFriend = $friendsarray[$i];
            $stmt->bindParam(':f_id'.$i,trim($nextFriend,'"'));
        }
        $result = $stmt->execute();
```

Now f_id is always null.

Comment: You need to set `$values` before you use it when assigning `$query`.

Comment: You assign `$friendarray`, but use `$friends` in the `foreach` loop.

Comment: The challenge is to do a single INSERT using a long VALUES list but still have all those values as bound parameters for injection-safety. I gave it a stab below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree the best strategy is to use a single query as you were trying to do. This will be much faster for long lists, especially if you don't wrap all the individual inserts into a single commit. This should work:

```
$friendarray = $_POST['Friends'];
$placeholders = [];
$user_id = $_POST[`user_id`];

for($i=0, $len=count($friendarray); $i < $len; $i++) {
    $placeholders[$i] = "(:u_id".$i.", :f_id".$i.")"; // entries like "(:u_id0, :f_id0)"
}

$query = "INSERT INTO up2_friends_to_users (u_id , f_id ) VALUES ".implode(",", $placeholders);
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
for($i=0, $len=count($placeholders); $i < $len; $i++) {
    // each binding must use a separate variable, not an array element
    $stmt->bindParam(':u_id'.$i, $user_id);
    // use your favorite escape function on the value here
    $nextFriend = $db->real_escape_string($friendarray[$i]);
    $stmt->bindValue(':f_id'.$i, $nextFriend);
}
```

EDIT: learned something new from [Only variables can be passed by reference - php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911096/only-variables-can-be-passed-by-reference-php). Can't pass array elements to bindParam as second parameter! Workaround posted above.

Comment: Typo: `$friendsarray` should be `$friendarray`.

Comment: by the way, using multiple INSERTS is probably reasonable but only if surrounded by beginTransaction() and commit() calls. I had a really bad performance hit on one memorable occasion where the reason was all the transactioning around each write.

Comment: The code seems to work, but I dont see any entry in my table. I will edit my post above.

Comment: @Konter I had missed a parentheses on the first bindParam. Can you output/inspect the $query string?

Comment: SQL Error: Only variables can be passed by reference in line 91 $stmt->bindParam(':f_id'.$i, $friendsarray[$i]);

Comment: @Konter I learned something new from this! See the edit above. Due to odd PHP restriction, I have to pull the array value out as a separate variable to bind.

Comment: Thanks the error is now gone, but now my array seems be empty, but my post.log shows all the values:
`SQLSTATE[21S01]: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
[class] => PDOStatement
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        ()
`

Comment: There was an extra set of parens around placeholder implode string, for example `((:f_id0, :u_id0), (:f_id1, :u_id1))`.  Removed in an edit, should work now.

Comment: I found two more typos, missing $ in an `[i]` and `.=` that should have been changed to `=` both in the line inside the `for` loop. Tested in a phpfiddle and it works.

Comment: I also had to at trim($nextFriend,'"'); on that bindParam, because the mysql value is an integer and the quotes where taken from the string values.
And I had to do explode(',',$_POST['friends']);

Comment: it is possible to get a posted value as an array without needing to explode() it, depending how you do your form. Does it make sense to use parseInt() instead of trim()?

Comment: If you use the same variable in all the `bindParam` calls, it won't work, since they'll all be references to the variable's last value. Use `bindValue` instead of `bindParam`, and then you should be able to use the array directly.

Comment: @Barmar ooh, good catch! In this case the $nextFriend variable is redundant, also, and one could inline it.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO up2_friends_to_users (u_id , f_id ) VALUES (:u_id, :f_id)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(':u_id', $_POST['user_id'];
$stmt->bindParam(':f_id', $friendid);

foreach ($_POST['Friends'] as $friendid) {
    $stmt->execute();
};
```

`bindParam` binds to a reference, so every time you execute the query it will use the value of `$friendid` from the current iteration of the loop.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, but wouldnt this execute the sql query multiple times instead of one single query?

Comment: Yes, it will. Unless there are hundreds of friends in the form, it's not a big deal, and using a prepared statement is best. Your code is subject to SQL injection.

Comment: The problem is that there will be something between 50 and 100 friends to add to the table, with every POST.

Comment: I don't think that's enough to cause a performance problem. But if you want to do it in one query, I think your code should work, as long as you fix the variable name that I mentioned in a comment.

Comment: @Konter see my post for doing in a single INSERT and still using bound params.

Comment: But you need to escape the data to prevent SQL injection, use `$db->escape($friendsarray)`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, something like this (using question mark parameters)?

```
$values = array();
foreach ($_POST['Friends'] as $friendid) {
    $values[] = $u_id;
    $values[] = $friendid;
}

$conn = new \PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$query = 'INSERT INTO up2_friends_to_users (u_id , f_id ) VALUES '
        . trim(str_repeat('(?, ?),', count($values / 2)), ',');
$conn->prepare($query)->execute($values);
```