# mysqli_stmt_bind_param - expects references

Tags: php, mysqli

I understand that we have to pass references to `mysqli_stmt_bind_param`. I am doing the following

```
    $ref = refValues($data);
    function refValues($arr){
        $refs = array();
        foreach($arr as $key => $value)
            $refs[$key] = &$arr[$key];
            var_dump(implode(",", $refs));
            return $refs;
    return $arr;
}
```

I am having all of my values in an array. I am using the above function to get the references. [`Got the above answer from SO`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16120822/mysqli-bind-param-expected-to-be-a-reference-value-given)

My PHP version is 5.6

I am binding the params in the following way.

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $types, $ref);
```

`$stmt` is a statement created through `mysqli_prepare`. It returns error number 0.

`$types` is nothing but `$types = str_pad('',count($data),'s');`

I have verified `$types` data also. It returns expected number of types. i.e `ssssssss`

If I execute, I am getting the following error.

```
 Only variables should be passed by reference in test.php
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911096/only-variables-can-be-passed-by-reference-php) solution in SO. I cannot assign 100 variables. I am not thinking that is feasible.

I found another alternative is `call_user_func_arrary`.

```
$values =  refValues($data);
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $values);
```

It returns `number of bind type doesn't match number of values`. It is weird for me. I have verified the array and values. Both counts are matching. I am not aware of internal implementation of call_user_func_array.

Please let me know is there any way to solve this efficiently.

Comment: Well, first off, `function refValues($arr){` creates a copy of `$data`

Comment: @Xorifelse Please see the updated link. 34 upvotes for the answer. Doesn't it create references?

Comment: In your code `$ref` is an array (value) that contains references.

Comment: And `bind_param` first argument is string of types.

Comment: @u_mulder Yeah. I understand that. Thanks. Please let me know when references are already there why that func expecting references? Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $types, $ref);
```

means that you have **one** reference to bind.

Why? Let's see:

- first argument is a statement
- second argument is a string with types
- **following** arguments are references to values which should be binded.

As you pass one argument (it is `$ref`) - you are trying to bind only **one** value. And `$ref` is **not** a reference, it is array of values which are refernces. See the difference? Array of references vs reference.

So, you took second approach, and it is a right one:

```
$values =  refValues($data);
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $values);
```

What's the error here? You didn't pass types `$types`:

```
// do not assign anything to a variable
// pass results of `refValues` directly to `call_user_func_array`
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), array_merge(array($types), refValues($data)));
```

What do we do here: we are trying to call `$stmt->bind_param` and pass to this function arguments as array.

What are the arguments of `$stmt->bind_param`?

- first argument is types (`$types`)
- following arguments are references to values (`$values`)

Now it should work.

Comment: I am getting ` Warning: Parameter 2 to mysqli_stmt::bind_param() expected to be a reference, value given` Any help?

Comment: @GopsAB use PDO

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible ways to avoid this hassle:

1. Use PDO. Your current problem is only the first out of many WTFs you will have with mysqli. In this particular case it would be as simple *and natural* as

   ```
   $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
   $stmt->execute($data);
   ```
2. Okay, you have such a whim of using mysqli. Then, as long as you are using a supported PHP version, [you can use a splat or a three dot operator](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/mysqli_comparison#splat):

   ```
   $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
   $types = str_repeat('s', count($data));
   $statement->bind_param($types, ...$data);
   $statement->execute();
   ```

Comment: Thanks. I'll think about upgrade to PDO.